# Is anyone held accountable when the Pentagon fails its audit?

Tags: united-states, military, corruption, bureaucracy, pentagon

[Bloomberg reports](https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/pentagon-fails-its-financial-audit-for-the-sixth-straight-year-1.1999291) that:

> The US Defense Department failed for the sixth consecutive year to
> score a clean financial audit, a goal routinely achieved annually by
> businesses that have a fraction of its $3.8 trillion in assets and $4
> trillion in liabilities.
>
> Pentagon officials nonetheless claimed significant progress in
> tracking its assets and correcting hundreds of deficiencies in its
> accounts.
>
> The failure “is not a surprise,” Pentagon Comptroller Michael McCord
> told reporters at the Pentagon. “It certainly is not something that we
> say, ‘it doesn’t matter.’”

Is anyone held accountable when the Pentagon fails its audit? The article mentions its the sixth consecutive year and that it has difficulty tracking its assets, so I am guessing no one is really held accountable.

Is this the case, or do some people have to explain and correct the discrepancies?

Comment: I don't get the comparison with businesses.  Surely it is much easier for a small business to keep track of assets than a huge organisation like the Pentagon. I think we also need to understand better what "fail an audit" means.  Does it mean that there was evidence of systematic fraud, or does it mean that there were errors in the accounts, for example paying twice for something due to an oversight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is anyone held accountable when the Pentagon fails its audit?

Sometimes.

If the DOD fails an audit, this could be one factor among others to suspend, fire, fail to promote, or reassign a civil service employee in the DOD who is arguably responsible for some or all of the problem. But, it is very difficult to successfully discipline civil servants for poor job performance in practice.

Political appointees can be fired by the President, or by other political employees to whom they report between themselves and the President, at will. And, usually, big enduring systemic problems that lead to a failure to receive a clean audit are mostly a result of bad decision making and a lack of leadership by senior political appointees. But, for a top level federal political appointee, with an average tenure of two years or so, getting fired, a few months earlier than you otherwise would have been for other reasons anyway, is just a fact of life and comes with the territory.

Ultimately, everyone who is involved in causing the problem is a government employee with no "skin in the game" unlike senior executives at private corporations who have big personal financial investments in their businesses that can be diminished by financial mismanagement. There is only so much that government employees have to lose.

The likelihood that a DOD employee or contractor who performed poorly or failed to display leadership in a manner that caused the DOD to fail some or part of its audit will be held legally and financially liable for this is extremely low, absent clear evidence of some sort of embezzlement, bribery, or similar corruption. Failing to do your job well can have employment consequences, but it isn't a ground for civil liability to your employer.

The DOD isn't a separate legal entity, so another part of the U.S. government can't sue it. That would amount to the United States suing itself, which it isn't allowed to do (honestly, there is even case law on that point).

Congress could mandate that the DOD and its officials take particular actions to cure the problem, and could use its power of the purse to penalize subdivisions of the DOD that don't comply, or could even reorganize the DOD more dramatically to address the problem.

But, ultimately, carrying out the laws is the President's job and not the job of Congress. If this part of the President's job doesn't get done right, there is only so much that Congress can do.

Congress might hold hearings and try to embarrass the officials that they believe are responsible, but there isn't so much else that Congress can do to hold a particular individual responsible for the institutional failures of the DOD and its financial and accounting systems.

> The US Defense Department failed for the sixth consecutive year to
> score a clean financial audit, a goal routinely achieved annually by
> businesses that have a fraction of its $3.8 trillion in assets and $4
> trillion in liabilities.

This statement by the source is just stupid. The bigger the organization is, the harder the job it is to account for its actions. It is much easier to account for a business with $3.8 billion in assets, $4 billion in liabilities, and 2500 employees, than it is to account for an entity a thousand times larger that is engaged in much more complex tasks, in much worse conditions, and that has to prioritize keeping national security secrets. The reality is that secrecy always undermines financial accountability, even if it is required for purposes other than to hide fraud, mismanagement, and waste. But you can't have a modern military that is effective without lots of secrecy.

> Pentagon officials nonetheless claimed significant progress in
> tracking its assets and correcting hundreds of deficiencies in its
> accounts.

One of the reasons that this is allowed to persist for so long is that the DOD is primarily charged with fighting wars, not with having its accounts perfectly in order. On the battlefield, we want policies that making winning wars and preserving the lives of our soldiers the first priority, while keeping track of where ammunition and equipment went is far down the list of priorities.

There are legitimate, real complaints in the military that current, inadequate, accounting requirements (e.g. to inventory equipment and ammunition regularly) is already compromising higher priorities. And, this is part of the reason that getting this fixed is not a top political priority for the President or DOD leadership or Congress.

Also, the story gets old. The current round of failed audits is six years running. Perennial poor accounting and waste and mismanagement in the military has been present since the American Revolution. Periods of time where this hasn't been a problem have been the exception and not the rule. Most politicians have accepted that the inability of the DOD to keep its property inventories and financial affairs in order is simply a fact of life, that is irritating and has to be dealt with now and then, like weeds in a garden, but is not a problem that will ever been solved once and for all in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: Is there even a single name or position, within the pentagon or in Washington, actually held responsible for the outcome of the audit?

Comment: The person at the top of the pyramid with respect to the audit is Department of Defense Comptroller Michael McCord. It doesn't appear that he suffered any negative consequences as a result of the audit results. *See* https://www.defense.gov/About/Biographies/Biography/Article/602736/mike-mccord/ It is possible that one or more of his subordinates experienced some negative consequences, but I'm not enough of a Beltway insider to know.